# Display None is taking space

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I need to hide a few items for category pages. When jquery triggers display: none, the element become visually hidden. However, it remains white space in its place. The items are generated by a loop, but it still keeps the white space, if I delete an element from the code using chrome's code inspector.

This is the theme of the page where I need to apply this: https://w8.foxdsgn.com/prague/work-grid/

In my code:

```css
.prague_gap_col15 {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}

.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.project-grid-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.project-grid-wrapper .project-grid-item-img-link {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 240px;
}

.project-grid-wrapper .project-grid-item-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% + 40px);
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.project-grid-wrapper .project-grid-item-content {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 17px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="row prague_grid prague_count_col3 prague_gap_col15 js-load-more-block no-footer-content prague-load-wrapper" data-columns="prague_count_col3" data-gap="prague_gap_col15" style="position: relative; height: 506px;">
        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapp portfolio-item-paralax  project_cat_10 project_cat" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
            <div class="portfolio-item">

                <div class="project-grid-wrapper">

                    <a class="project-grid-item-img-link" href="http://localhost/k2ah/works/23" target="_self" style="height:370px;">
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb1" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/23/thumb1.jpg');"></div>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb2" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/23/thumb2.jpg');"></div>
                    </a>

                    <div class="project-grid-item-content">
                        <h4 class="project-grid-item-title"><a href="http://localhost/k2ah/projects/23" target="_self">Project A A</a></h4>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-category">X, Y</div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
                                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapp portfolio-item-paralax  project_cat_11 project_cat" style="position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 0px;">
            <div class="portfolio-item">

                <div class="project-grid-wrapper">

                    <a class="project-grid-item-img-link" href="http://localhost/k2ah/works/24" target="_self" style="height:370px;">
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb1" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/24/thumb1.jpg');"></div>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb2" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/24/thumb2.jpg');"></div>
                    </a>

                    <div class="project-grid-item-content">
                        <h4 class="project-grid-item-title"><a href="http://localhost/k2ah/projects/24" target="_self">Project A B</a></h4>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-category">A, B</div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
                                <div class="portfolio-item-wrapp portfolio-item-paralax  project_cat_11 project_cat" style="position: absolute; left: 800px; top: 0px;">
            <div class="portfolio-item">

                <div class="project-grid-wrapper">

                    <a class="project-grid-item-img-link" href="http://localhost/k2ah/works/25" target="_self" style="height:370px;">
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb1" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/25/thumb1.jpg');"></div>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb2" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/25/thumb2.jpg');"></div>
                    </a>

                    <div class="project-grid-item-content">
                        <h4 class="project-grid-item-title"><a href="http://localhost/k2ah/projects/25" target="_self">Project B B</a></h4>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-category">M, T</div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The element I need to hide are with the class name: ".project-grid-wrapper"

I looked into the main theme (https://w8.foxdsgn.com/prague/work-grid/), tried to hide an element using code inspector, even tried by deleting an element. The same thing happening. It is keeping white space for that element, even though the element is not present in the code.

[image: Screenshot of Element taking Space]

Now, I am a bit clueless and need expert advice.

Thanks in advance for being so cool. :)

Comment: `display` won't release it. Use `visibility:hidden`

Comment: visibility: hidden has the same effect here. Just tried, not working.

Comment: Try hiding `.portfolio-item-wrapp`

Comment: display: none is the right thing to use to stop the element taking any space (visibility: hidden just stops it showing, the space is still taken) so it must be that an ancestor element is holding the space and is the one which needs to be set to display: none.

Comment: Display and visibility aren’t having any effect because you’re positioning each of the ‘portfolio-item-wrapp’ divisions using `position: absolution,` I’m assuming using JavaScript. If you’re going to continue positioning each of the images using code, you’ll need to trigger a resize event to cause the browser to recalculate where everything should be, or you could just use flex.

Comment: @AHaworth, I thought so as well. Tried all the idea came to my mind. I must be missing something.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it shows empty spaces when element is hidden, is because all elements are positioned with `position: absolute`, they have hard-coded coordinates.

So instead, you could try use `display: grid` for the main container:

```css
.prague_gap_col15 {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}

.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.project-grid-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.project-grid-wrapper .project-grid-item-img-link {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 240px;
}

.project-grid-wrapper .project-grid-item-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% + 40px);
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.project-grid-wrapper .project-grid-item-content {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 17px 0;
}

/*added*/
.prague_grid
{
  --colWidth: 150px; /* max width per column */
  --colNum: 3; /* number of columns */
  --colGap: .5rem; /* gap between columns */ 
  max-width: calc((var(--colWidth) + var(--colGap)) * var(--colNum));
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: var(--colGap);
  align-items: flex-start;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(var(--colWidth), 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="row prague_grid prague_count_col3 prague_gap_col15 js-load-more-block no-footer-content prague-load-wrapper" data-columns="prague_count_col3" data-gap="prague_gap_col15">
        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapp portfolio-item-paralax  project_cat_10 project_cat">
            <div class="portfolio-item">

                <div class="project-grid-wrapper">

                    <a class="project-grid-item-img-link" href="http://localhost/k2ah/works/23" target="_self">
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb1" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/23/thumb1.jpg');"></div>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb2" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/23/thumb2.jpg');"></div>
                    </a>

                    <div class="project-grid-item-content">
                        <h4 class="project-grid-item-title"><a href="http://localhost/k2ah/projects/23" target="_self">Project A A</a></h4>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-category">X, Y</div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapp portfolio-item-paralax  project_cat_11 project_cat">
            <div class="portfolio-item">

                <div class="project-grid-wrapper">

                    <a class="project-grid-item-img-link" href="http://localhost/k2ah/works/24" target="_self">
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb1" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/24/thumb1.jpg');"></div>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb2" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/24/thumb2.jpg');"></div>
                    </a>

                    <div class="project-grid-item-content">
                        <h4 class="project-grid-item-title"><a href="http://localhost/k2ah/projects/24" target="_self">Project A B</a></h4>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-category">A, B</div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapp portfolio-item-paralax  project_cat_11 project_cat">
            <div class="portfolio-item">

                <div class="project-grid-wrapper">

                    <a class="project-grid-item-img-link" href="http://localhost/k2ah/works/25" target="_self">
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb1" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/25/thumb1.jpg');"></div>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb2" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/25/thumb2.jpg');"></div>
                    </a>

                    <div class="project-grid-item-content">
                        <h4 class="project-grid-item-title"><a href="http://localhost/k2ah/projects/25" target="_self">Project B B</a></h4>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-category">M, T</div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-item-wrapp portfolio-item-paralax  project_cat_11 project_cat">
            <div class="portfolio-item">

                <div class="project-grid-wrapper">

                    <a class="project-grid-item-img-link" href="http://localhost/k2ah/works/25" target="_self">
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb1" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/25/thumb1.jpg');"></div>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-img project-thumb2" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/k2ah/resources/projects/25/thumb2.jpg');"></div>
                    </a>

                    <div class="project-grid-item-content">
                        <h4 class="project-grid-item-title"><a href="http://localhost/k2ah/projects/25" target="_self">Project B A</a></h4>
                        <div class="project-grid-item-category">M, T</div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And for the sake of sanity, avoid use in-line styles...always.

Comment: Thank you so much. I Will let you know the outcome. :)